# Opencart invoice not showing MRP?

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

Opencart Invoice is not shwoing MRP it only choose minmum price between MRP and Special Price and display as Price in Invoice. Can any body please tell me how to do MRP Implementation in Invoice.

Thanks In Advace

Comment: when customer checkout they can see MRP price their confirm page.? and you mean only Invoice you have problems..?

Comment: Actually i want to show MRP with Special price on my Invoice. Which is usually Printout bill for customers. Thanks